# My Odoo Discuss App is Not Update the Chat/Not Realtime

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, odoo, odoo-16

So I just installed Odoo 16 CE Version in my Ubuntu server. I already configure the nginx and the odoo.conf, but the realtime chat is not working.

Then I test the Discuss App. I make 2 users and I use 2 browser. Browser A using user A, and Browser B using user B. But the chat is not in realtime. I have to refresh the page to make the chat appear. Then I tried to access my server with 8072 port (domain.com:8072) which is the port for realtime chat, and it works.

Why does it happen?

This is my Nginx conf

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
    server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
    server_name portoko.com;
    # Add Content-Security-Policy header
add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';

proxy_read_timeout 720s;
proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
proxy_send_timeout 720s;

Redirect websocket requests to odoo gevent port
location /websocket{
proxy_pass http://odoochat/;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

log
access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

Redirect requests to odoo backend server
location / {
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass http://odoo/;
}

common gzip
gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
gzip on;


client_body_in_file_only clean;
client_body_buffer_size 32K;
client_max_body_size 500M;
sendfile on;
send_timeout 600s;
keepalive_timeout 300;
```

And this is my odoo.conf

```
admin_passwd = -
db_host = localhost
db_name = False
db_password = -
db_port = 5432
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template0
db_user = limomoli
dbfilter = %h$
list_db = False
http_port = 8069
logfile = /var/log/-/odoo.log
addons_path=/limomoli/odoo/addons,/odoo/custom/addons
proxy mode = True
workers = 15
limit_memory_hard = 15360000000
limit_memory_soft = 12288000000
max_cron_threads = 2
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 600
limit_time_real = 1200
log_level = debug_rpc
longpolling_port = 8072
xmlrpc_port = 8069
```

Can you guys help me, please? Thank you